# Get control properties with javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, gridview

I'm trying to access control's properties and although it works great in `IE6`, in FF3, it fails.  I'm doing:

```
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).style.display);
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).style);
```

And the first one shows a blank popup while the second shows `'undefined'`.

I do

```
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).id);
```

and I get the proper ID of the box along with:

```
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId));
```

and I get that in an HTML table.

This works perfectly in IE but not FF.  What do I need to do to get this functioning?

Edit: gridViewCtlId is defined as:

```
var gridViewCtlId = '<%=GridView.ClientID%>';
```

Here is the full code:

```
var itemVisible= '<%=ItemVisible.ClientID%>';

function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx)
{
    alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).style.display);
    alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).style);
    if (document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).disabled == false)
    {
        alert("hi1");
        var selRowCCA = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);
        if (curSelRow != null)
        {   
            alert("hi2");
            var previousRow = getSelectedRow(previousRowIndx);

            var CountIdx = previousRowIndx % 2;
            if (document.getElementById(itemVisible) == null)
            {
                if (CountIdx == 0)
                {
                    alert("hi");
                    previousRow.style.backgroundColor = 'Silver';
                }
                else
                {
                    previousRow.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
                }
            }
        }

        if (null != selRow)
        {
            alert("new");
            previousRowIndx = rowIdx;
            curSelRow = selRow;
            selRow.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty much an onClick where I have to call that function to turn it back to its original color (using alternating color rows).  IE, this works fine.  If i do the first alert

```
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId).disabled);
```

I would get either true or false.
The reason it's like this is because someone is going to enter something in a text box and the first `gridview` is going to populate depending on whats in that `textbox`.  Then when someone selected something in the first gridview, that `gridview` is going to become disabled and then populate a second.  So i'm having an issue checking for the disabled part of the `gridview`.

Comment: Are you missing " " around the element ID in the call to getElementById or is that a typo in the questions?

Comment: It's not, its defined elsewhere by:

    var gridViewCtlId = '<%=GridView.ClientID%>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gridViewCtlIdCCA = 'test';
alert(document.getElementById(gridViewCtlIdCCA).style);
</script>
```

Alerts `[object CSSStyleDefintion]` in Firefox 2 and 3.

If `.style` where undefined, `.style.display` would produce an error, not alert an empty dialog (unless you are capturing `window.onerror`).

Can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. More information about SSCCE available [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html).